# Why can I protect a closed question?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, protected-questions

Consider this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7551/1426227). It has been *closed* as primarily opinion-based, so it cannot accept any answers. Quoting [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions):

> **What happens when a question is closed?**
>
> Once a question has been closed, it will no longer accept new answers [...]

However such question can still be *protected*. From [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/protect-questions):

> **What are protected questions?**
>
> A protected question prevents answers being added by anonymous and very new users. [...]

Why can I protect a question that doesn't accept answers at all?

Comment: Presumably a closed question can be re-opened and remain protected?

Comment: MSE duplicate: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222173/do-not-allow-me-protect-closed-questions

Comment: Protection is mostly useless anyway. The spam protection on the site has been significantly improved since that feature was invented. And it doesn't really work from preventing new users from vandalizing canonical posts with trash answers, since you only need some 10 rep to override the protection.

Comment: They just didn't write the code to special-case it.  There was in general an assumption back then that users wouldn't try illogical things.  Fairly sure the codebase is not lean anymore today :)  Not a good thing btw.

Comment: @user2285236 Post an answer here with a quote from the MSE duplicate answer ;)

Comment: it works in the rare cases when new users (or users with only 101 rep awarded by association bonus because association bonus doesn't count for protected questions) who post lame answers to classics that already have 20+ good answers.

Comment: Does "Protect" still block commenting?

Comment: @Joshua:  I don't recall protecting ever blocking comments.  You may be thinking of locked questions, which is something only diamond moderators can do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Tim Post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/50049/tim-post) has [answered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222174) a [duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/222173) question on [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/), where he writes:

> It is a bit of a quirk, but while the action is available to you, we don't expect that you'd use it unless you were doing so for a very specific purpose (such as noted in comments, a case where a spam magnet might be headed to reopening).

If you want to know why [animuson](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/141525/animuson) "waits for the reports of Stack Exchange users setting their cars on fire to hit the major news outlets", you should read the rest of the answer.

<sub>Thanks to [user2285236](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2285236/user2285236) for finding the [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) [duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/222173) and reporting it in a [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/619442).</sub>